# Eliminar ficheros de un servidor desde un trigger MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estimados amigos:

Tengo el siguiente código en una disparador de MYSQL

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mfnmlsbase`.`post_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `post` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM ficheros WHERE ficheros.fic_token_padre = old.pos_token;
END
```

Como veis,al eliminar un registro en la tabla 'post' se eliminan tambien todos los registros asociados de la tabla ficheros, que básicamente contiene urls de los ficheros (imágenes) relacionados con el registro eliminado en la tabla post.

La pregunta. ¿ Se puede modificar el trigger para borrar tambien los ficheros del servidor ?, es decir las imágenes. Ya que ahóra, las imágenes que utilizaba el post eliminado, quedan como ficheros en el servidor que no son utilizados por ningún otro post.

Quizá no se pueda y resulte necesario eliminarlos desde PHP. ¿ Alguien puede arrojarme algo de luz sobre esto ?

Gracias por vuestro tiempo

Comment: Como poder se puede, pero no te lo recomendaría directamente desde el trigger. No es bueno combinar lógica de datos con lógica física, lo que sí podrías insertar los ficheros en una tablas de `ficheros_a_eliminar` y mediante algún tipo de tarea programada fuera de los horarios de alto uso, hacer la eliminación física de estos archivos.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh, no se me ocurrio eso. Creo que lo hare así. Muchas gracias.